# What does it mean to both append and prepend a value to a variable (in fish shell or in general)?

Tags: programming, fish

Per the [fish shell documentation for the `set` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html):

> **append**: causes the values to be *appended* to the current set of values for the variable. This can be used with *--prepend* to both
> append and prepend at the same time.
>
> **prepend**: causes the values to be *prepended* to the current set of values for the variable. This can be used with *--append* to both append
> and prepend at the same time.

In quotidian English, **append** means *to add*, and **prepend** means *to add at the beginning*. Clearly, these meanings don't apply to fish (or to computers in general?), for it's redundant to say that we can both *add x to y* while also *adding x to the beginning of y*. If we can do the latter, then we can do the former. That is to say, by doing the latter, we do the former. If it's senseless to say that I am both running a race from the starting line and also running a race, then it's senseless to say that I am both prepending some data and also appending that data.

So, what do these terms mean to fish (or in the world of software development)? What are the implications for doing one over the other? And what does it mean to explicitly do both?

Answer (score 5):

Just like it says, it both appends and prepends ***if both options are given***

```
$ set list 1 2 3
$ set -S list
$list: set in global scope, unexported, with 3 elements
$list[1]: |1|
$list[2]: |2|
$list[3]: |3|
```

```
$ set --append --prepend list 4 5 6
$ set -S list
$list: set in global scope, unexported, with 9 elements
$list[1]: |4|
$list[2]: |5|
$list[3]: |6|
$list[4]: |1|
$list[5]: |2|
$list[6]: |3|
$list[7]: |4|
$list[8]: |5|
$list[9]: |6|
```

Answer (score 4):

**append**: Add something to the end.
**prepend**: Add something to the beginning.

What you're adding to and what *something* is depends on context.  Consider, for example, a list of integers:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

If I *append* 4 (the something), then I get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
          ^
```

If I then *prepend* 5 (again, the something), I get:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 ^
```

Another context where you might see this is strings.  Consider, for example, a string:

```
"abc"
```

If I *append* d, then I get:

```
"abcd"
    ^
```

If I then prepend e, I get:

```
"eabcd"
 ^
```

If I want to both append and prepend an element, then I apply both operations with the same element.  For example, say I want to both append and prepend f, I'd get:

```
"feabcdf"
 ^     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

> In quotidian English, **append** means *to add*, and **prepend** means *to add at the beginning*.

Perhaps you're thinking of *add* as the math operation, where it is commutative: 5+2 = 2+5. *[Append](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/append)* and *prepend* would be better defined with *attach*, *affix*, or (colloquially) *tack onto*.

In general use, *append* may or may not imply affixing to the end: a book's *append*ix is affixed to the end of the text, but your *append*ix is affixed to somewhere on your large intestine (in fact, near the beginning).
But in the context of code, and specifically manipulation of strings and arrays, *append* implies affixing *to the end*.

Therefore:
*Prepend `foo` to `bar`* results in `foobar`.
*Prepend `2` to `5`* results in `25`.
*Append `foo` to `bar`* results in `barfoo`.
*Append `2` to `5`* results in `52`.

Comment: Yes, as any cursory check of the word *append* will reveal, at root it means "To add subordinately". I even have a dictionary of synonyms which explains in detail just that. After the months that have passed since I started learning coding, I now see that programmers generally don't understand this at all. They only understand their own specific usage. I'm not going to to debate language with programmers anymore.

Comment: As you can see, someone downvoted your answer because of what I'd call willful ignorance, as well as utter negligence (to look it up).